# Para que sirve añadir #native-browser en una url

Tags: html5

Hola tengo una duda de para que se utiliza el añadir al final de una url lo siguiente: #native-browser?

Comment: eso me parece mas como abrir un modal.

Comment: A que te refieres a modal?

Comment: me refiero a que en bootstrap tu abres un modal una ventana en el centro de la pagina oscurecida, entonces ese `#native-browser` seria el id del modal, pero en todo caso podrias editar esa pregunta , ya qeu contiene muy poca infomacion, podrias poner codigo.

Comment: Realmente esto me lo ha comentado un cliente de si servia el #native-browser ponerlo en un enlace tal que asi http:www.facebook.com/#native-browser, debido a que antiguos programadores le habían dicho que era para abrir ese enlace con el idioma del navegador. Y para mi es la primera vez que lo he escuchado

Comment: yo tampoco he escuchado de eso, a lo mejor es verdad , pero eso esta en una etiqueta a href?

Comment: Os comento. Esto es a que tengo un wordpress y con la web de reskyt.com para hacer apps necesito este  paranetro oara abrir las url de ls redes sociales

Comment: AitorUdabe, en realidad es un indicador, probablemente tu página al cargar la url con este indicador realiza una tarea determinada. Como ejemplo tengo una aplicación iOS en la cual cuando cargo una url con #open_browser, al detectar eso la url se abre en el navegador del dispositivo y no dentro de la aplicación, yo puedo definir que hace mi página al cargar ese valor en la url.